# How google analytics keeps referral informations

Tags: google-analytics

How google analytics keep track of webpages which are posted in Social sites having.
The posts have links to third party shortener tool which redirect to main web page.

Eg:

Let a website provide link shortening service. If a user has shortened his links using the service it post it on the social networking websites like twitter, facebook.

The link will be redirect to service provider webpage and from there it will again redirect to original location. So how google will track it. Please comment if my question is not clear. I will elaborate it more.

Comment: Is this question is not clear?

Comment: Yes, you might want to work on the clarity of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer the question even though it's not completely clear to me.

Most shortner services will create a 30X HTTP redirect to the final destination. For example the link bellow is a 301 redirect to my personal blog. Browsers follow 30X redirects but keep the original referral as an HTTP header and that is accessible on the page via a javascript API.

http://goo.gl/fbFsu

When you land on my site execute `document.referrer` on the console and you should see stackOverflow as the referrer, even though you passed through goo.gl for the redirect.

Not all services use HTTP redirects though. Twitter's t.co for example doesn't. So twitter.com will never show up in Google Analytics report as a referral source. Instead you'll see t.co.

There's a good reason for that. Before twitter introduced t.co it was very hard to measure twitter audience. That comes from the fact that twitter users very often use client applications (eg: TweetDeck) and in those cases there's no referral and those visits are accounted as direct visits instead.

Now that twitter has t.co all links posted on twitter are wrapped around t.co redirects and are reported on Web Analytics tools as referrals from t.co regardless of the fact that the user is using a client or the usual twitter website.

For other networks like Google Plus or facebook it's not a problem, because the user is always accessing the interface via the website.